# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException error in IE but the same code works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, iedriverserver

I have written a login script and when I execute it using ChromeDirver and FFDriver it works fine. But when I run the same using IE Driver it fails and giving the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #mod\-login\-username
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'LENOVO', ip: '192.168.1.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:39714/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: af1a703a-0216-4c67-8c51-1292d13e399c
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=mod-login-username}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at pageObjects.Admin_Login.txtbx_Username(Admin_Login.java:13)
    at testcases.testcase01.main(testcase01.java:29)
```

Here is the script:-

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Admin_Login {

    private static WebElement element = null;

public static WebElement txtbx_Username(WebDriver driver) {

    element = driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-username"));

    return element;
}

public static WebElement txtbx_Password (WebDriver driver) {

    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("mod-login-password"));

    return element;
}

public static WebElement btn_Login (WebDriver driver) {

    element = driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-password"));

    return element;
}
}
```

I'm not getting why the script showing the error of "Unable to find element with css selector ..." as I have only used id to find the element and not CSS selector. Could anyone please advise.

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML please ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #mod\-login\-username
```

...implies that the **InternetExplorerDriver** was unable to locate any element as per the *Locator Strategy* you have used.

### Reason

As you have mentioned the same code works using ChromeDirver/Chrome and GeckoDriver/Firefox, it is worth to mention that different *Browser Engine* renders the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) differently. So brittle *Locator Strategies* may not work across all the browsers.

---

As per your question, `script showing the error of "Unable to find element with css selector ..." as I have only used id` it is again worth to mention as per **WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft** the preferred [Locator Strategies](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) enlisted are as follows :

- **`"css selector"`** : CSS selector
- **`"link text"`** : Link text selector
- **`"partial link text"`** : Partial link text selector
- **`"tag name"`** : Tag name
- **`"xpath"`** : XPath selector

Snapshot :

[image: Locator Strategies]

A change was propagated through the respective **client** specific bindings. For the **`Selenium-Java`** clients here is the [client code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/W3CHttpCommandCodec.java#L205) where internally the *Locator Strategies* based on **`id`**, and **`name`** are **internally converted** to equivalent **css selector** through a switchcase as follows :

```html
        switch (using) {
          case "class name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "." + cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "id":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "#" + cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "link text":
            // Do nothing
            break;

          case "name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "*[name='" + value + "']");
            break;

          case "partial link text":
            // Do nothing
            break;

          case "tag name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "xpath":
            // Do nothing
            break;
        }
        return toReturn;
```

Snapshot :

[image: JAVA_classname_id_name_tagname]

Hence though you provide:

```
(By.id("mod-login-username"))
```

Error shows:

```
Unable to find element with css selector == #mod\-login\-username
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But, I'm trying to performing crossbrowser tests. So how should i handle such scenarios as you explained that Browser Engine renders the HTML DOM differently. Is there a work around to this? How the tests should be written so that it will be accepted within all browsers. Thanks in Advance @DebanjanB

Comment: @Kaustubh There won't be any deviation (significant difference) if your _Locator Strategies_ are optimized.

Comment: Yes! I did. :) Sorry, but can you please help me or just give me idea to start with - how to optimise Locator Strategies. Thanks in Advance! @DebanjanB

Comment: @Kaustubh Though my opinion will be based on expertise and experience but try using the `class` attribute as a mandatory measure coupled up with `id`, `name`, etc use the `tagName` exclusively.

Comment: Great! Understood. Thanks for help.