# Cannot click Sign In button on Outlook with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I'm having trouble clicking the following button on Outlook:

```
<a data-m="{"cN":"SIGNIN", "sN":"P6", "pV":"1"}" href="https://outlook.live.com/owa/?nlp=1" class="internal sign-in-link" data-task="signin">Sign in</a>
```

I've attempted both of the following code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]"))).click();
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@data-task='signin']"))).click();
```

The terminal sends a vague NoSuchElementException for both of them.

Could the Xpaths be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy full Xpath from **Google Chrome browser** and just paste in your code. To copy it press **Ctrl+Shift+I**, find the element and click on **Copy >  Copy Full Xpath**.

This is your full xpath:

```
/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a
```

This python code below works for me:

```
#python solution
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element with text as **Sign in** instead of using *ExpectedConditions* of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Sign in"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.internal.sign-in-link[data-task='signin']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='internal sign-in-link' and text()='Sign in']"))).click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [**NoSuchElementException**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) in:

- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)
- [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException error in IE but the same code works fine in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781651/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-error-in-ie-but-the-same-code-works-f/50793527#50793527)