# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element error clicking on the Sign up button using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I'm trying to test out the first name section of this link (https://softwaretestinggn8fe.herokuapp.com/) using selenium in java to show that the error message "First Name can only contain characters." will be shown when I type "545" into the first name section of the website. However my test fails and this is the error I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='submit']"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
    import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    
    public class WebTesting {
        
        @Test
        public void test1() {
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/mtecl/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");    // configure path to the driver
            
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
            driver.get("https://softwaretestinggn8fe.herokuapp.com/");
            
            //Username
            WebElement testUsername = driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")); //id: first name
        
            testUsername.sendKeys("545");
            
            //Button
            driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
            
            String expected = "First Name can only contain characters.";
            String actual = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/main/div[2]/form/div[1]/span")).getText();
            
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no element with name submit. Just type submit.

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element <kbd>Sign up</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://softwaretestinggn8fe.herokuapp.com/");
  WebElement testUsername = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#firstname")));
  testUsername.sendKeys("545");
  testUsername.submit();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input#firstname +span"))).getText());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://softwaretestinggn8fe.herokuapp.com/");
  WebElement testUsername = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='firstname']")));
  testUsername.sendKeys("545");
  testUsername.submit();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='firstname']//following-sibling::span[1]"))).getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  First Name can only contain characters.
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: FirstName]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [**NoSuchElementException**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) in:

- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)
- [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException error in IE but the same code works fine in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781651/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-error-in-ie-but-the-same-code-works-f/50793527#50793527)